# Website posted the following command, what does it do?

Tags: vbscript, command

I found the following command

```
slmgr.vbs /upk
```

which website's URL is available upon request, and I was wondering what it actually does.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from `slmgr.vbs /?`:

```
/upk [Activation ID]
    Uninstall product key
```

The `Activation ID` is a GUID generated upon product key installation, which can be displayed by the command `slmgr.vbs /dlv` (display verbose license information):

```
Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, OEM_COA_SLP channel
Activation ID: cc9e90a9-f94b-4795-98c1-83e8cb5b8908
...
```

`slmgr.vbs` is a tool for managing Windows product keys and activation, which was introduced with Windows Vista.